# Flutter Circular progress indicator not working properly on android

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter

I'm building an app with flutter, and I have some issue with loadings on android: I have several futureBuilder, with `CircularProgressIndicator()`
and, while on IOS they all work properly, on android I got a single dot showed instead of the loading symbol.

Here is the sample code, and below two screen for both IOS and android in order.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: myFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<VtsAccount> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Center(child: Text('Error');
            else {
              return RichText(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                text: TextSpan(
                    text: snapshot.data.myField()),
              );
            }
          }
        });
```

[image: This is IOS]
[image: This is android]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If I use as Future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 5)) it works also on android, but I need to call an external library that rise this issue

Comment: An external library? Wow. Try this. Delete the Future.delayed code you added.. Ends the the async method used by the FutureBuilder with 'return await .....'

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this "dot effect"? I have the same issue. It only goes away when I hot reload/restart.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same 'dot effect' on CircularProgressIndicator with the code below:

```
return Container( width:1,height: 1,child:Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()));
```

Im sure that the problem is you are not giving space enough to the parent widget of CircularProgressIndicator Widget

(Im dont know why in IOS the behaviour is different)

Comment: I tried to give more space to the parent but this does not change the behavior

Comment: this doesn't have do anything with the parent widget size, its the implementation using future builder that's affecting the indicator